# Zend Framework .css Images Not Displaying

Tags: php, css, image, zend-framework

The images in my ZF2 .css file aren't showing on the web site.  This is an example from my 'base-asset' project CSS file:

```
background-image: url(/rons-home-images/Rons_Home.png);
```

1. I updated the web site with Composer.
2. Then I erased the /public/asset folder.
3. I restarted PHP and memcached
4. After this I did "CTRL-F5".  All the web site images populated /public/asset/rons-home-images .

But the ronshome.css file path didn't change to reflect where the cached images are actually stored.  For the images to display on the screen the path is:

```
/asset/rons-home-images/Rons_Home.png
```

I originally created base-asset for a different web site.  I keep both web site images separate I created /public/rons-home-images for this web site.  Is there a setting some where that I am missing where I need to tell Zend Framework or Composer that the images path is different?

Comment: ZF isn't going to touch your CSS file (unless you're using some third party plugin that generated said file). If the paths are incorrect in the stylesheet you need to correct them.

Comment: Tim Foundation If I set the CSS file to match the path then the images don't populate /public/asset/rons-home-images .

Comment: I will look into this more